# Hibernate: Multiple tables, same object

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate

I am trying to write a simple app that contains one table that keeps track of payments each user has made and a second table that contains total amount each user has paid (sum of all payments). Currently, both tables have the same fields (firstName, lastName, amount) and I have mapped them from the same Java class
and I have trouble mapping that class to multiple tables. Is there any simple solution to this?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Payment")
public class Payment{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @Column
  @NotNull
  private String firstNname;

  @Column
  @NotNull
  private String lastNname;

  @Column
  @NotNull
  private double amount;

... Constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Could you please show code that you have tried  and problematic place.

Comment: Honestly, there is very little code, because when I wrote entity I realized that I have no idea how to map to two tables. Anyhow, please give me a sec and I will post what I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

`@MappedSuperclass`
`public class ClassWithTheFields{`
`\\Not annotated with @Entity`
`@Id private Integer Id;`
`...`
`}`

`@Entity`
`public class EntityClass extends ClassWithTheFields{}`

`@Entity`
`public class AnotherEntityClass extends ClassWithTheFields{}`

This way, both classes extending ClassWithTheFields will have the same fields, but will be mapping different tables.

You just need to put all the common fields in a class annotated with @MappedSuperclass, but not@Entity, and then extend this class in other classes annotated with @Entity.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `@SecondaryTable` [annotation](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/SecondaryTable.html).

Something like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_PAYMENT")
@SecondaryTable(name = "MY_PAYMENT_DETAILS",
    pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "pd_payment_id"))
public class Payment {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "p_id")
   private Long id;
   
   @Column(name = "p_first_name")
   private String firstNname;

   // ...
   
   @Column(name = "pd_amount", table = "MY_PAYMENT_DETAILS")
   private double amount;
}
```

This is assumed that you have the following schema:

```sql
create table MY_PAYMENT
(
   p_id number,
   p_first_name varchar(200),
   CONSTRAINT MY_PAYMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY(p_id)
);

create table MY_PAYMENT_DETAILS
(
   pd_payment_id number,
   pd_amount number,
   CONSTRAINT MY_PAYMENT_DETAILS_PK PRIMARY KEY(pd_payment_id),
   CONSTRAINT MY_PAYMENT_DETAILS_FK foreign key(pd_payment_id) references MY_PAYMENT(p_id)
);
```

See also [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-custom-crud-secondary-table-example) section of hibernate documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You should go with @MappedSuperclass. It's the easiest choice for you.